# ListView performItemClick doesn't scroll after onActivityResult

Tags: android, listview, click

In my app, I have two scenarios in which I need to refresh a ListView (customersList):

1) When searching for customers, I have to handle suggestions item click in a SearchView

2) When I want to display new customer created in another activity

I have single method responsible for refreshing the ListView:

```
private void showCustomer(Integer customerId) {

    ListView customersList = (ListView) findViewById(id.list);

    if(customersList != null) {
      Integer listId = getItemPositionByAdapterId(customersList.getAdapter(), customerId);
      customersList.performItemClick(
        customersList.getAdapter().getView(listId, null, null), 
        listId,
        customersList.getAdapter().getItemId(listId)
      );
      customersList.requestFocusFromTouch();
      customersList.setSelection(listId);
    }
}

private int getItemPositionByAdapterId(ListAdapter adapter, final long id)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++)
    {
        if (adapter.getItemId(i) == id)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

The showCustomer() method is called in two places:

```
/**
 * Scenario 1: Handle suggestions item click
 */
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
  if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())) 
    Uri data = intent.getData();
    String customerIdString = data.getLastPathSegment();
    Integer customerId = Integer.parseInt(customerIdString);

    if (customerId != null) {
      showCustomer(customerId);
    }
  }
  super.onNewIntent(intent);
}

/**
 * Scenario 2: Handle new customer creation
 */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

  // Check which request we're responding to
  switch (requestCode) {
    case RESULT_CUSTOMER_ADD:
      // Make sure the request was successful
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Integer customerId = data.getIntExtra(MyContract.CustomersEntry._ID, 0);
        // This one doesn't work as expected!
        showCustomer(customerId);
      }
    break;
  }
}
```

When calling from onNewIntent() (suggestions item click), everything works fine - the item is selected and the List is scrolled to the item.

When calling from onActivityResult(), the item is selected, **but the List doesn't scroll** to apropriate element.

I'm out of ideas. Why isn't it working in same way in both cases? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could you try :
    smoothScrollToPostion(listId) in showCustomer method instead requestFocusFromTouch()? i am not able to try it now so i will wait for your response.

Comment: That helped! I will use smoothScrollToPositionFromTop() because it has duration as a parameter. Thank you.

Comment: @schabluk i'm glad that i helped ^_^